# A different approach to the strong Goldbach conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Consider the set A of prime numbers $p_i$ such that $p_i+6$ is not prime (listed in OEIS 140555; see comments thereto).  Let 'Goldbach representation' mean a pair of odd prime numbers which sum to a given even number.

<strike>Theorem</strike> Conjecture: For any even number $E>6$ which has a Goldbach representation consisting of two members of set A, there is at least one other Goldbach representation of $E$ which contains at least one prime number which is not a member of set A.

My questions are: can anyone prove this <strike>theorem</strike> conjecture? Or suggest how to attack it? Has this approach to Goldbach been pursued before?

Comments: If Goldbach is false, then there is an integer $K$ such that $2K$ is the smallest number that has no Goldbach representation.  The following argument is true for all appropriate values of $a$ (and the <strike>theorem</strike> conjecture could be restated for other values of $a$, using sets defined as $p_i$ such that $p_i+2a$ is not a prime), but I will discuss the specific instance of $a=3$. Since $N=2(K-3) < 2K, N$ has a Goldbach representation.  However, if either of the primes in any Goldbach representation of $N$ can be supplemented by 6 to yield another prime, then $2K$ itself will have a Goldbach representation, which is counter to our assumption.  So if Goldbach is false, all Goldbach representations of $2(K-3)$ must contain only members of A.  Hence, proving the <strike>theorem</strike> conjecture stated is equivalent to proving Goldbach.  Note that even if the <strike>theorem</strike> conjecture as stated (i.e. for $a=3$) is not true, the restatements of the <strike>theorem</strike> conjecture for every appropriate value of $a$ must also fail in order for the Goldbach conjecture to be false.  Thus the Goldbach conjecture is equivalent to saying that there is some value for $a$ for which a <strike>theorem</strike> conjecture of the form given is true.

Comment: For the "Theorem" you'd need at least $E>6$, since it's not true for $E=4,6$.

Comment: Right. I knew that and blew right by it in the post, which I've now corrected.

Comment: How can you title this, "a **different** approach...," and then ask whether this approach has been pursued before? If you don't know whether the approach has been pursued before, please edit the word "different" out of the title.

Comment: A more concise statement of the "conjecture" would be "Every even number $E\gt6$ that has a Goldbach representation has a Goldbach representation which contains at least one prime number which is not a member of $A$." By the way, "$\{A\}$" denotes the set containing a single object $A$; what you mean is just "$A$", the set called $A$.

Comment: My math dictionary defines 'theorem' as (1) A general conclusion proposed to be proved upon the basis of certain given hypotheses (assumptions). (2) A general conclusion which has been proved.

Comment: @KeithBackman: Throw it out and buy a new math dictionary.

Comment: Responsive to joriki's comment: Let set B contain all prime numbers $p_i$ such that $p_i+6$ is prime (OEIS listing A023201). Then every even number $E>6$ that has a Goldbach representation, has a Goldbach representation which contains a member of B.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Come on, it's clear he thinks it's different or novel but knows he's imperfect and thus wants a second opinion. Seems fine to me!

Comment: @Trevor, when I posted that comment – nine years ago! – the title didn't have the question mark in it. The title wasn't asking, it was asserting. OP edited the question mark into the title, possibly in response to my comment.

Comment: My faint recollection is that I did in fact add the '?' to the title in response to @Gerry Meyerson comment

Comment: @GerryMyerson Complaint retracted, and man did I feel silly noticing a few minutes later that this was from '12. I have to say I'm impressed that not one but TWO of the commenters are apparently still active on a daily basis.